# How did they get the lava to Ballona Creek?

Tags: plot-explanation, volcano

In the 1997 movie "Volcano", the protagonists divert the flow of lava at Beverly Center by using explosives to dig a trench that takes it to Ballona Creek, which then leads to the ocean. The movie has numerous scientific inaccuracies, but I found it entertaining nonetheless. One thing really bothers me, though. Looking at a map of L.A., it's obvious that Ballona Creek doesn't come anywhere NEAR Beverly Center, whereas in the film the trench only had to extend a few city blocks (see map below).

**Has anyone involved with the film addressed this particular discrepancy?**

SCALE: The map below is from Google Maps. The distance from the red circle to the nearest point of the blue line is just under 8 miles.

---

**UPDATE:** Just checked the scene in question again, and missed a detail. The trench they make goes to a large concrete drainage ditch, which THEN leads to Ballona Creek. Still, though, that's several miles instead of the short distance portrayed in the film.

[image]

Comment: Just curious, what's the scale on the map you're displaying? Or what's the actual distance from the main eruption site to Ballona Creek?

Comment: It's about 5 miles from Fairfax and 6th (the yellow "(" mark) to Venice and Hauser (the end of the blue mark), for example. It's 5.5 miles from 3rd and La Cienega (the red circle) to Hauser and Venice.